# How do I map a vector to a map, pushing into it repeated key values?

Tags: vector, clojure, hashmap

This is my input data:

```
[[:a 1 2] [:a 3 4] [:a 5 6] [:b \a \b] [:b \c \d] [:b \e \f]]
```

I would like to map this into the following:

```
{:a [[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]] :b [[\a \b] [\c \d] [\e \f]]}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
(defn- build-annotation-map [annotation & m]
 (let [gff (first annotation)
       remaining (rest annotation)
       seqname (first gff)
       current {seqname [(nth gff 3) (nth gff 4)]}]
   (if (not (seq remaining))
     m
     (let [new-m (merge-maps current m)]
       (apply build-annotation-map remaining new-m)))))

(defn- merge-maps [m & ms]
  (apply merge-with conj
         (when (first ms)                                                                                                              
           (reduce conj                     ;this is to avoid [1 2 [3 4 ... etc.                                                                                                          
                   (map (fn [k] {k []}) (keys m))))                                                                                    
         m ms))
```

The above produces:

```
{:a [[1 2] [[3 4] [5 6]]] :b [[\a \b] [[\c \d] [\e \f]]]}
```

It seems clear to me that the problem is in `merge-maps`, specifically with the function passed to `merge-with` (`conj`), but after banging my head for a while now, I'm about ready for someone to help me out.

I'm new to lisp in general, and clojure in particular, so I also appreciate comments not specifically addressing the problem, but also style, brain-dead constructs on my part, etc. Thanks!

**Solution** (close enough, anyway):

```
(group-by first [[:a 1 2] [:a 3 4] [:a 5 6] [:b \a \b] [:b \c \d] [:b \e \f]])
=> {:a [[:a 1 2] [:a 3 4] [:a 5 6]], :b [[:b \a \b] [:b \c \d] [:b \e \f]]}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
(defn build-annotations [coll]
  (reduce (fn [m [k & vs]]
            (assoc m k (conj (m k []) (vec vs))))
          {} coll))
```

Concerning your code, the most significant problem is naming. Firstly, I wouldn't, especially without first understanding your code, have any idea what is meant by `annotation`, `gff`, and `seqname`. `current` is pretty ambiguous too. In Clojure, `remaining` would generally be called `more`, depending on the context, and whether a more specific name should be used.

Within your let statement, `gff (first annotation)
                            remaining (rest annotation)`, I'd probably take advantage of destructuring, like this:

`(let [[first & more] annotation] ...)`

If you would rather use `(rest annotation)` then I'd suggest using `next` instead, as it will return `nil` if it's empty, and allow you to write `(if-not remaining ...)` rather than `(if-not (seq remaining) ...)`.

```
user> (next [])
nil
user> (rest [])
()
```

In Clojure, unlike other lisps, the empty list is truthy.

[This](https://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/clojure/Clojure_Library_Coding_Standards) article shows the standard for idiomatic naming.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Works at least on the given data set.

```
(defn build-annotations [coll]
  (reduce
    (fn [result vec]
      (let [key (first vec)
            val (subvec vec 1)
            old-val (get result key [])
            conjoined-val (conj old-val val)]
        (assoc
          result
          key
          conjoined-val)))
    {}
    coll))

(build-annotations [[:a 1 2] [:a 3 4] [:a 5 6] [:b \a \b] [:b \c \d] [:b \e \f]])
```

I am sorry for not offering improvements on your code. I am just learning Clojure and it is easier to solve problems piece by piece instead of understanding a bigger piece of code and finding the problems in it.

Answer (score 4):

Although I have no comments to your code yet, I tried it for my own and came up with this solution:

```
(defn build-annotations [coll]
  (let [anmap (group-by first coll)]
    (zipmap (keys anmap) (map #(vec (map (comp vec rest) %)) (vals anmap)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my entry leveraging group-by, although several steps in here are really concerned with returning vectors rather than lists.  If you drop that requirement, it gets a bit simpler:

```
(defn f [s]
  (let [g (group-by first s)
        k (keys g)
        v (vals g)
        cleaned-v (for [group v]
                    (into [] (map (comp #(into [] %) rest) group)))]
    (zipmap k cleaned-v)))
```

Depending what you actually want, you might even be able to get by with just doing group-by.

Comment: `group-by` does exactly what I need, actually. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn build-annotations [coll]
  (apply merge-with concat 
         (map (fn [[k & vals]] {k [vals]}) 
              coll))
```

So,

```
(map (fn [[k & vals]] {k [vals]}) 
     coll))
```

takes a collection of [keys & values] and returns a list of {key [values]}

```
(apply merge-with concat ...list of maps...)
```

takes a list of maps, merges them together, and concats the values if a key already exists.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually my preferred solution so far. I like its conciseness, and your explanations are very clear.